# Execute javascript from bundles in Document.ready

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-optimization

I use the MVC4 default template.

I add a script : `MyScript.js` in `/Scripts/MyApp/`  with a function :

```
function Testing()
{
    alert('test');
}
```

In the global.asax :

```
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/myapp").Include(
    "~/Scripts/MyApp/MyScript.js"));
```

I'd like call this method in `/Views/Home/Index.cshml`

I tried the code below but without success:

```
<script type="text/javascript" lang="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        Testing();
    });
</script>    

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/myapp")
```

When I look the source code the link to `MyScript.js` is there and I can navigate to it (go to the source)

But the `Testing()` method in the  `$(document).ready` is not executed.

**Update1**

```
<script type="text/javascript" lang="javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert("test");
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting you inline script after the bundle inclusion. Also the `lang` attribute on the `script` tag is deprecated:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/myapp")

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        Testing();
    });
</script>
```

---

UPDATE:

OK, I think you forgot to include jquery, so the `$` function not defined :-)

So if you want to do it with bundles:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/myapp").Include(
    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js", "~/Scripts/MyApp/MyScript.js")
);
```

or if you don't want to use bundles:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/scripts/MyScript.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        Testing();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you see some javascript errors in the console? Do you have javascript enabled in your browser?

Comment: I think you simply forgot to include jquery.

Comment: you are right, it's the error in the console but ... when I look he source code, there is a link to jqeury (working link). In the layout page, I have this :         
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

Comment: But where is it? It must be included **before** your script. The custom section must be before your inline script in which you are using the `$` function.

Comment: About your update, I have to include the jQuery in each bundle ?

Comment: @Kris-I, it depends. If your other scripts depend on jquery it is obvious that you must include it.

Comment: If I need jquery in the _layout page and in some other view, need to include twice, not a problem that ? jQuery was include in _layout

Comment: No, that's a problem. You should include jquery only once. Otherwise it seems like a waste to me.

Comment: By default the @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/myapp") is in the bottom of the _layout page. I moved it, first line after <header> and it's ok